# When do references to threads in java go out of scope?

Tags: java

When we define new threads in Java, when do the thread's references go out of context? For example, if I create a `WeakHashMap<Thread, Object>` when would an entry of a dead thread be dropped from this Hashmap?

Also in case a thread pool is used to execute some task(`Runnable`), will that reference from the hashmap be ever dropped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thread is a garbage collection root as long as it is alive. Once it terminates it would be eligible for dropping from the weak hash map.

For the second part, reference to what? If reference to the Runnable task, the reference held by the threadpool will go away once the pool completes executing the task. The threads in the pool will keep executing tasks until the pool is shutdown or until they die due to an uncaught exception.

Comment: > A thread is a garbage collection root as long as it is alive.

So if I have a static `WeakHashMap` that has a reference to a thread I spawn, run a runnable and shut it down, it'll be removed, right? Also in the second part, I meant to ask: If I execute a runnable using a ThreadPoolExecutor and want to store data associated with thread executing this runnable in the map, will it be dropped when runnable execution completes? But as you specified, threads in a pool don't die after execution, so I guess this ref won't be dropped.

Comment: @ayush: not clear what you mean by “store data associated with the thread”.

Comment: I have some information(metrics stored in an object) associated with each thread(currently as a threadlocal variable). When I spawn a new thread, I want the child thread to have this information, add to it and give this back to the parent but dont want to do this explicitly by passing an object and returning this object because this information is metric related and not actual business logic. Also instead of passing it around in every method, we've used a static ThreadLocal variable to store this info(which I intend to replace by the map, and hence this question about possible memory leaks.)